# Google Bigquery Billing Tier not working using python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am using below function to run query ,other queries are running fine but few complex queries are giving error as "needed billing tier greater than 1", even though i have provided max billing tier as 7 it's taking deafault billing tier i.e 1 . Any loop i need to include here??

```
from gcloud import bigquery
import uuid
import time

query1="""complex query"""

def save_query_to_table(project, query, dataset, table):
    print "Using project: ", project
    dest_client = bigquery.Client(project=project)
    table = dest_client.dataset(dataset).table(table)
    if table.exists():
        table.delete()

    source_client = bigquery.Client(project=project)
    query_job = source_client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)
    query_job.allow_large_results = True
    query_job.destination = table
    query_job.use_legacy_sql = True
    query_job.maximum_billing_tier = 7
    #print query_job.query
    query_job.begin()    

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        save_query_to_table('project-123-abc'',query1,'dataset_final','base_training')
```

ERROR:
Errors:
Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 3 or higher required. (error code: billingTierLimitExceeded)
Job ID  dataset_test:ca8e642e-27c9-414a
Creation Time   May 16, 2017, 8:10:26 PM
Start Time  May 16, 2017, 8:10:27 PM
End Time    May 16, 2017, 8:12:39 PM

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting please? Also, I noticed you are using legacy SQL. Is that intended?

Comment: yes i am using legacy SQL as requirement, adding error snippet.